# Extending Managed paths in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, url, managed-path, extended

Can the managed paths in SharePoint Online be extended.

I understand that "teams" and "sites" are the only available managed paths.

Can we extend them to something like

"Teams/abc/" and "sites/xyz/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. By default only sites and teams are available and that's it. You can't add/extend managed paths.